# How to automatically call onClick for a Button when application is opened?

Tags: java, android

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loadFeed(statutory);
        }
    });
}
```

I want my app to automatically call `onClick` for my `Button b1` when I open my application.

How can I make my app automatically call `onClick` when the app is opened?  I am looking for a modification to my existing code to accomplish this.

Comment: bad elaboration,what thing you need, not clear here

Comment: his question seems clear to me.  I have the same question. I want an EditText box to be in focus and the soft keyboard open and waiting for input when the Activity starts.

Comment: The Q is perfectly clear. The usual suspects feigning confusion.

Answer (score 4):

If I got you right, and you need to genereate click event on activity start, add

```
b1.performClick();
```

after setting listener. Yet I don't understand why can't you just call `loadFeed(statutory);` directly

Comment: plz tell me complte code ..i gave my code for button1 i have to set automatic if i will open my application

Comment: what do you mean by "automatic"? onCreate() is run when your application is started.

Comment: Just add the above b1.performClick() event after your existing code.

Answer (score 3):

If you want something automatic then put that code inside a function and call it from inside the `onCreate()` function.

For example:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        function();
    }

    public void function() {
        // Your code here
    }

}
```

Comment: +1, But he already want to call a function loadFeed(statutory); so he can directly call that function inside the onCreate() method.

Comment: @Paresh,Thanks.That my answer is saying, isnot it?

Comment: Yes Android Power, just check my +1 sign :)

Comment: Thanks Paresh you are dude of android.You have also given some answer of question and those were helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Instead why don't you call your loadFeed(statutory) directly in onCreate() method, if you do this then it will get automatically called when your application gets start.

### Update:

Actually, i don't know about [performClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick%28%29) method existed there, so just use button1.performClick() after assign click listener for your button. Thanx sagar for the pointing it out.

Comment: You can generate click event. use b1.performClick();

Comment: @Sagar Thanx sagar for the pointing it out.

Comment: but why should he if just calling the method is much easier?

Comment: @banzai86 : ya there is no reason to use performClick(); Just added that part for information  on how to generate click event. Ideally we should just call a method.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question i understood that you have written a button click listener and the code you have written in that..you want to execute it automatically when the Activity starts

As you have implemented a Listener that will get executed only when the appropriate event occurs for the Activity Start there are events that you can use are like onCreate() and onReStart()

But you can't call any event listener without happening of the event.

doucmentations about the events and listeners those are used listed below and you can also make custom listener but cant call any listener like a function

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/library/Basics_of_Event_Management/

http://tseng-blog.nge-web.net/blog/2009/02/17/how-implement-your-own-listener-android-java/

**ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION:
You will need to write a FUNCTION for the code implementation and call it in your onClick() and also in onCreate()**

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in your code

```
b1.performClick();
```

in onCreate() Method.

Answer (score 0):

```
final Timer t = new Timer();
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Your Actions
        t.cancel();
    }

},5000);
```

After 5 seconds (5000 ms) action will perform.

Answer (score -1):

For that you have to call listener on the app, eg:

```
onCreate()
{

    button.setOnclickListner(this);
}
```

and put action on:

```
    button.setOnclickListner(this);
   {
         #action
   }
```

Comment: plz frnd tell me complte code accrding to my given code